# How to ensure that AMD dependency has been loaded from inside <script> tag code?

Tags: webpack, requirejs, amd

I've migrated all the scripts that were included in my page to webpack bundle, and now I include only this.

How should I migrate my code (inside page `<script>` tags) in order to be compatible with AMD module loading? For example my existing code cannot access `$` (jquery global object) anymore, (probably because it is not yet loaded) when the code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expose-loader` module.

Then in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {


    module: {

        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: '$'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: 'jQuery'
                    }]
            },

        ]
    },
```